# Failed to execute sqlite3 in C application

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm trying to display history of firefox and chrome  using C Application .For the history of chrome , it works well because the Sql command doesn't contain symbols but with chrome My sql request contains symbols , So this function doesn't give me result .It give me error :

> no such table :moz_historyvisits

Or ,when i test this request from the command prompt it works well . What i think that the problem is the sql request contains (_)symbols . 
Rq : For chrome history it works well . CallbackFirefox is to function to display result
I'm using windows and Code blocks as an IDE . When i execute select name from sqlite_master
[image]

```
int DisplayFirefoxHistory()
    {
     sqlite3 *db;
    char *err_msg = 0;

    system("cd C:/Users/******/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/*.default");
    int rc = sqlite3_open("places.sqlite", &db);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    sqlite3_close(db);
           return 1;
        }

char *sql = "select url,datetime(visit_date/1000000-11644473600,'unixepoch') from  moz_historyvisits,moz_places order by visit_date desc";

        rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callbackFirefox, NULL, &err_msg);

        if (rc != SQLITE_OK ) {

            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to select data\n");
            fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", err_msg);

            sqlite3_free(err_msg);
            sqlite3_close(db);

            return 1;
        }

        sqlite3_close(db);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is opening the right database?

Comment: Yes , the problem that when I  copy and paste the same sql command in Command Prompt it works well . It cannot be problem of environment or library because sqlite3 works when displaying chrome history

Comment: You say yes, and yet your code is reporting it cannot find the table in your SQL which you've proved exists by running the SQL in the command line tool. Try replacing your SQL with "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master" and print out the results to see what tables your code is finding

Comment: Sorry , it displays me this . moz_historyvisits,moz_places exists . I add image to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
system("cd C:/Users/******/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/*.default");
```

`system()` starts a separate shell that is terminated after the command was executed, so this does not change the current directory of your actual program.

You should find out the directory name manually, and include it in the database file name.